# Accessing Google Cloud SQL from Google Compute Engine using private network

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

is it possible to access Google Cloud SQL from Google Compute Engine using the private network?

It appears that Google Cloud SQL sees the public network IP for the Google Compute Engine instance.

And, the web console doesn't allow entering the instance private address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it is not possible to access Google Cloud SQL instances via a private IP address.

This [this page](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/gce-access) confirms this, it says **Note: You must use the external (public) IP address of the GCE instance** ...when configuring **Authorized IP Addresses** to your cloud sql instance from your GCE instance.

Answer (score 5):

This is now available via private services access and VPC Network Peering.

The announcement:

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/introducing-private-networking-connection-for-cloud-sql

Details:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/private-ip

Answer (score 0):

You can't access cloud sql from a private IP address but you can whitelist NAT instance's Public IP in order to access cloudsql from private server.